# pythonaddins interactive output registry to a shapefile recursively

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-addin

I am using pythonaddin's `onMouseDownMap` to get flow paths interactively and add each line drawn to a shapefile. "line" shapefile is created each time using `arcpy.RasterToPolyline_conversion` whenever I click on map but sometimes not registered in `AddasStreams.shp`. Any suggestions where this is falling?

```
class FlowPaths(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = False
        self.cursor = 3

    def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):
        # add line to view -- addOutputsToMap 
        arcpy.env.addOutputsToMap = True
        point = arcpy.Point(x,y)
        ptGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)
        theLine = arcpy.sa.CostPath(ptGeometry, optfolder + '/dem', optfolder + '/flowdir', "BEST_SINGLE")
        arcpy.RasterToPolyline_conversion(theLine, "line", "NODATA", "", "NO_SIMPLIFY", "VALUE")
        searchcursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("line", ("OID@","SHAPE@"))
        firstrow = searchcursor.next()
        insertcursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(optfolder + '/AddasStreams.shp',("Id","SHAPE@"))
        insertcursor.insertRow(firstrow)

        del firstrow,insertcursor,searchcursor
```

Comment: Since arcpy.da became available at 10.1, I cannot think of a use case for `searchcursor.next()`.  You seem to be mixing old style (arcpy) and new style (arcpy.da) coding patterns.

Comment: suggesting that I should instead use `arcpy.SearchCursor` consistently?

Comment: No - I only ever use arcpy.da cursors nowadays.